# Summernote airmode: Trigger airmode on click, not on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, summernote

I'm using summernote airmode to create inline editor, but currently its only shows the editor when user select/highlight the text (see pict). What I want is to trigger the airmode editor when on focus/click then text (not selecting it). I don't know how to do this, please help.

This is my current summernote airmode: [here](http://muhammadibnuh.net/sandbox/)

HTML

```
<div id="test">
   <h1>Hello, I'm calvanery</h1>
   <h4>Select me</h4>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
  $('#test').summernote({
    airMode: true,
    callbacks: {
             onFocus: function () {
             console.log('Editable area is focused');

             }
         }
  });
</script>
```

[image: editor shows when user select/highlight text]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Add onFocus in Summernote options:**

```
callbacks: {
   onFocus: function () {
       $(this).next().find(".note-editable").selectText();
   }
}
```

**Jquery selectText addon:**

```
jQuery.fn.selectText = function () {
    var doc = document;
    var element = this[0];
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(element);
        range.select();
    }
    else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
};
```

This will select the text on click, and it will open the popover.

Comment: I have tried this, found it on google from summerntoe github issues before I ask question here, and I don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

I separated the text and the toolbar and implemented draggable functionality on the toolbar. It is not airmode but it can still answer your question.

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Summernote with Bootstrap 4</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.15/dist/summernote-bs4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.15/dist/summernote-bs4.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-2">
                  <div id="summernote"></div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="draggable"></div>

<script>


    $(function(){
        $('#summernote').summernote({
            callbacks: {
                onChange: function(contents, $editable) {
                    console.log('onChange:', contents, $editable);
                    var htmlContent = $('#summernote').summernote('code');
                    var k=$(htmlContent).text();
                },
                onInit: function() {
                    $(".draggable").append($(".note-toolbar "));
                    console.log('Summernote is launched');
                }
            },
            toolbar: [
            // [groupName, [list of button]]
            ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
            ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
            ['color', ['color']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
            ['height', ['height']],
            ['view', ['undo', 'redo']]
          ]
        });

        $(".draggable").draggable();
    })
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```